# Nexus Repository - Azure DevOps Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, nexus3, azure-devops-server-2020

I am trying to download my uploaded artifact from nexus repository manager in azure devops release pipeline with the help of **Sonatype Nexus Repository Release Artifact**.

However, I have created **service connation** and configure and then I am trying to use in release pipeline but it is throwing below error:

Service Connection Configuration:

[image: Sonatype Nexus]

Error:

```
Failed to query service connection API: 
'http://servername:8081/repository/Row/service/local/all_repositories'. Status 
Code: 'NotFound', Response from server: '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>404 - Nexus Repository Manager</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

**Could any one help me to identify issue?**

**Refrence link:**  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=soft-cor.nexus-custom-release-artifact-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed two configuration:

**In Release Pipeline:**

```
1. mavenrepov2 to MavenRepoV3.
```

In the Service connection:

```
2. Repository URL :  http://servername:8081
```

Now It is working fine

[image: Release Pipeline Configuration]